# What would the Riemann Hypothesis mean for the Prime Number Theorem?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, riemann-hypothesis, chebyshev-function

The Prime Number Theorem states $\pi(n)\sim \dfrac{n}{\ln n}$.

Would there be an equally simple expression if Riemann's Hypothesis were proved true?

From [Chebyshev Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_function#The_Riemann_hypothesis), would $\pi(n)\sim \dfrac{n}{\ln n} + \sqrt n\ln n$ work?

Addendum : A relevant link : https://mathoverflow.net/questions/70713/error-term-of-the-prime-number-theorem-and-the-riemann-hypothesis

Comment: https://www.jstor.org/stable/2005976?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly what you mean. $\pi(n)\sim n/\ln n + \sqrt n/\ln n$ is true unconditionally, because $n/\ln n + \sqrt n/\ln n\sim n/\ln n$.

Comment: could we have 'more asymptotic to'? otherwise PNT is as good as it's going to get

Comment: One idea would be to consider the upper bound for the error term $\pi(n)-n/\ln n$. Is that closer to what you mean? If so, [this](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/70713/error-term-of-the-prime-number-theorem-and-the-riemann-hypothesis) is relevant.

Comment: @Wojowu; i think i want to use pi(x) ~ x/logx + x/(logx)^2 + o() from your link, but as stated previously the asymptotes don't work

Comment: if the RH was true, the residual would be $\pi(x) - x/\ln x = \mathcal{o}(x^{1/2+\epsilon})$ for all $\epsilon > 0$. the residual would be $\pi(x) - x/\ln x = \mathcal{O}(x^{\sigma_0} / \ln x)$ if $\zeta(s)$ had a finite number of zeros at $\Re(s) = \sigma_0$ (if the RH was false)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, if the RH were proved true, then the error term for $\pi(x)$ in terms of $Li(x)$ would be optimal, namely
$$
| \pi(x) - Li(x) | = O(\sqrt{x}\log{x}).
$$
But since we can relate $\frac{x}{\log(x)}$ with $Li(x)$, we would also obtain a version with $\frac{x}{\log(x)}$. We have
$$
  {\rm Li} (x) - {x\over \log x} = O \left( {x\over \log^2 x} \right) \; . 
$$
Formulated differently, PNT only gives
$$
 \pi(x)={\rm Li} (x) + O \left(x \mathrm{e}^{-a\sqrt{\log x}}\right) \quad\text{as } x \to \infty
$$
for some constant $a>0$, whereas with RH we get even
$$
 \pi(x) = {\rm Li} (x) + O\left(\sqrt x \log x\right). 
$$

Comment: What would this "version with $x/\log x$" actually be, though?

Comment: The series at the end isn't convergent for any $x$.

Comment: What do you mean take the first terms? First how many? Isn't that an arbitrary decision to make since the terms fo the series get larger and larger?

Comment: What is the $a$ in the $\mathcal O(xe^{-a\sqrt{\log x}})$?

Comment: @Soke: The first terms, see the answer [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/70713/error-term-of-the-prime-number-theorem-and-the-riemann-hypothesis).